# C++ Socket Prograamming UDP Two way Communication

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am getting -1 from sendto() function and I don't know why. I have tried many things but nothing seem to work?
I can get msg from client but I can not send msg from server to client.

```
char msg[100]="hellloo";
int conn_sock;
struct sockaddr_in server,client;
conn_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

server.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(2219);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

socklen_t len = sizeof(server);

bind(conn_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,len);



while(strcmp(msg,"QUIT") !=0) 
    {       
        recvfrom(conn_sock,&msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,(socklen_t *)&client);
        cout<<"Data received from the Client : "<<msg<<endl;
        //cout<<"Client Address "<<inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr)<<endl;
        //cout<<"Client Port "<<ntohs(server.sin_port)<<endl;   

        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
        cout<<"Write Msg : ";   
        cin.getline(msg,sizeof(msg));
        socklen_t l = sizeof(&client);
        int n = sendto(conn_sock,&msg,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,l); 
        cout<<n<<endl;          
        //cout<<"Client Address "<<inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr)<<endl;
        //cout<<"Client Port "<<ntohs(server.sin_port)<<endl;   

    }
close(conn_sock);
return 0;
```

Comment: When a system call returns `-1`, use `perror()` to print the error message.

Comment: it shows address family not supported by protocol

Comment: @Barmar  can u tel me what to do now ?

Comment: You have a typo in the `recvfrom` call. `(socklen_t *)&client` should be `(socklen_t *)&len`.

Comment: So you're overwriting the `client` address structure with the length of the structure.

Comment: Thx for the help it is working now @Barmar But can you tell me why this error was creating problem.

Comment: Got it thank you for the help

Comment: The first member of `sockaddr` is the address family. Your mistake was overwriting the address family with the length.